# Inserting Javascript (Adsense) between a grid loop of posts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

My site, dadgab.com (Wordpress) has a 2 column loop with 4 rows.

**Header**
X X 
X X 
X X 
**Footer**

I would like to insert adsense javascript into the spot where the 3rd post would be (middle left). After running in circles all week trying to implement this, hoping someone on here can help me.

Here is my loop in index.php:

```
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('box'); ?>>
                <div class="post-image">
                    <?php
                        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
                        $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 300, 150, true ); //resize & crop the image
                    ?>
                    <?php if($image) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img width="300" height="150" src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?>" /></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
```

I have tried adding various methods including adding the following text to functions.php and adding a blank post, tagged with 'adsense'. This just yields an empty box, though if I actually click on the post the ad will display.

```
    add_filter('the_content', 'replace_adsense_posts_excerpt');
function replace_adsense_posts_excerpt($excerpt)
{
    $post = get_post(get_the_ID());
    if (has_tag('adsense ', $post)) {
        // Replace the content with our adsense code
        $excerpt = my_adsense_code();
    }
    return $excerpt;
}

function my_adsense_code()
{
    $adsense = 'ADSENSE CODE';

    return $adsense;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a counter to your loop and output the code if the counter equals 3:

```
<?php $i=0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $i++;?>
     <?php if($i==3):?>
         <div <?php post_class('box'); ?>>ADSENSE CODE</div>
     <?php endif;?>
     <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('box'); ?>>
         ....
```

You will need to use css to maker sure `adsense` is the same dimensions as the articles

Comment: I tried this (see my site currently dadgab.com). The ad did indeed display, however the post to the right of it was 'pushed' down, the ad is on the row by itself.

Comment: @DadGab - It sounds like you're missing the styling. Once you apply the correct CSS it will align normally

Comment: I've added the folllowing: '.adsense { 
width: 300px;
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
}' but the issue persists. I did find in the existing theme css this which styles the boxes '.box{
 width: 300px;
 float: left;
 
}

.box.odd{
 margin-right: 20px;
}

.box.even{
 margin-right: 0px;
}'

Comment: @DadGab Ok, looks like odd/even is important - see my edit, using `post_class` function - this should fix the issue